# PL/SQL function to receive a number and return its binary format

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g, plsql

I'm trying to write a function to receive a number and return its binary format. This is what I've developed so far and it's ok for inputs : 4,8,16 but it does not return correct binary format for other numbers.
I could not find the problem and I was wondering if you could find the problem?

```
create or replace function Show_Binary(i_Number in Number) Return Varchar2 
  AS

     V_Binary varchar2(50) := '';
     i_Number2 Number := i_Number;
       Begin
         While i_Number2>=2 LOOP

          V_Binary := V_Binary || Remainder(i_Number2, 2);
          i_Number2 := i_Number2 / 2;

       End LOOP;
          V_Binary := V_Binary || TO_CHAR(i_Number2);
          select reverse (V_Binary) into V_Binary from dual;
      return (V_Binary);
   End;
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is not an Oracle or PL/SQL issue, but a matter of implementing the proper algorithm.

Here is an example:

https://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Binary

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION dec2bin (N in number) RETURN varchar2 IS
  binval varchar2(64);
  N2     number := N;
BEGIN
  while ( N2 > 0 ) loop
     binval := mod(N2, 2) || binval;
     N2 := trunc( N2 / 2 );
  end loop;
  return binval;
END dec2bin;
/

SQL> SELECT dec2bin(22) FROM dual;
DEC2BIN(22)
----------------
10110
```

The overhead of LISTAGG + hierarchical query + other SQL functions is bigger than the overhead of a simple PL/SQL function.

```
SQL> with g as (select * from dual connect by level <= 1000) select count(distinct dec2bin(rownum)) as bincd from g,g;

     BINCD
----------
   1000000

Elapsed: 00:00:13.75

with g as (select * from dual connect by level <= 1000),
g2 as (select rownum as r from g, g)
select count(distinct bin) as bincd from (
select (SELECT LISTAGG(SIGN(BITAND(r, POWER(2,LEVEL-1))),'') 
       WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY LEVEL DESC) bin
FROM dual
CONNECT BY POWER(2, LEVEL-1)<=r
) as bin 
from g2
);

     BINCD
----------
   1000000

Elapsed: 00:00:35.53
```

And this is without the [UDF Pragma](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/udf_pragma.htm#LNPLS1851). On 12c and above the usage of the function gets slightly faster with the addition of `PRAGMA_UDF`.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION dec2bin (N in number) RETURN varchar2 IS
  PRAGMA UDF; -- <==================================================== MAGIC
  binval varchar2(64);
  N2     number := N;
BEGIN
  while ( N2 > 0 ) loop
     binval := mod(N2, 2) || binval;
     N2 := trunc( N2 / 2 );
  end loop;
  return binval;
END dec2bin;
/

SQL> with g as (select * from dual connect by level <= 1000) select count(distinct dec2bin(rownum)) as bincd from g,g;

     BINCD
----------
   1000000

Elapsed: 00:00:12.01
```

Comment: thanks a lot . I've changed this line of my code to this and my query and everything is ok now .  i_Number2 := trunc(i_Number2 / 2) . I had to use trunc function.

Comment: Szia @BalazsPapp - I know that you're pretty hot with Oracle - would it not be better to use SQL as per my answer - I seem to have read that performance-wise, it's better to use SQL first, **then** PL/SQL? Does Oracle do pure binary arithmatic without moving back and forth between strings?

Comment: @Vérace That is typically true when someone does row-by-row processing in PL/SQL instead of pure SQL. But that is not a general truth, see my update.

Comment: @BalazsPapp - thanks for that explanation. Obviously rules of thumb are not universal truths! :-) I'll try and bear that in mind. I'd love to have Tom Kyte's runstats to hand to really drill down on this issue - but, so many intereting questions, so little time! :-)

Comment: Just a note, `MOD()` works properly only up to numbers 2**127.

Comment: When my factory is producting its ( (2**127) + 1 )-th widget, I'll start to worry! :-)

Answer (score 4):

No need to use a function - you can do it in (Oracle's) SQL.

```
SELECT LISTAGG(SIGN(BITAND(43, POWER(2,LEVEL-1))),'') 
       WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY LEVEL DESC) bin
FROM dual
CONNECT BY POWER(2, LEVEL-1)<=43;
```

Result:

```
BIN
101011
```

I found this deadly snippet [here](https://sqlpatterns.wordpress.com/2017/05/25/integer-to-binary-conversion-in-oracle-sql/) and the fiddle is [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=17cec6af8aaf7ec565a8d87ac294e824). For the number 43, just substitute your column of choice. It's probably possible to do this using recursive `CTE`s, but that's a bit above my pay grade :-).

And to reverse the process, you can use this snippet

```
WITH INPUT AS
(SELECT REVERSE('1000') AS X FROM DUAL)
SELECT SUM(TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(X,LEVEL,1)*POWER(2,LEVEL-1))) AS OUTPUT
FROM INPUT CONNECT BY LEVEL<=LENGTH(X);
```

Result:

```
OUTPUT
8
```

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6358082/how-to-convert-a-byte-string-to-a-number-in-oracle) - dbfiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=6b5bdcc0eccb3ec3d2cd33b2a114f40e). Again, a recursive `CTE` might do the trick. Again, for '1000', just substitute your column.

Just for kicks, I found another function which will work (with tweaks) on older versions of databases that don't have recursive CTEs. From the **excellent** Orafaq site [here](http://www.orafaq.com/forum/t/155101).

```
SELECT 
  DECODE(BITAND(VALUE, 128), 128, '1', '0') ||
  DECODE(BITAND(VALUE, 64), 64, '1', '0') ||
  DECODE(BITAND(VALUE, 32), 32, '1', '0') ||
  DECODE(BITAND(VALUE, 16), 16, '1', '0') ||
  DECODE(BITAND(VALUE, 8), 8, '1', '0') ||
  DECODE(BITAND(VALUE, 4), 4, '1', '0') ||
  DECODE(BITAND(VALUE, 2), 2, '1', '0') ||
  DECODE(BITAND(VALUE, 1), 1, '1', '0') as bin_number from 
(select 8 as value from dual) A;
```

Result:

```
MY_BIN
1000
```

Fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=c88c9c05ef7a31fd5a013599ac620217). The more observant among you will notice that that code does not remove leading zeros - the code above has to be encase (entombed?) in this snippet

```
select replace(ltrim(replace(ColumnName,'0',' ')),' ','0')
```

which can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11978913/470530).